# Profiling mongodb with JProfiler

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy, jprofiler

I would like to profile some `mongodb` calls using `JProfiler`. I built a simple groovy script which uses the `com.mongodb` driver to connect to a `mongodb` database and fires some queries.

I configured JProfiler as instructed in this video:
http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2013/07/profiling-mongodb.html

My script is quite simple, but I cannot see any calls in the mongodb tab in JProfiler.

```
println "Starting client "+getName()
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("mongohost", 27017)
DB db = mongo.getDB("databasename")

// get a single collection
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collectionname")

DBCursor cursor = collection.find()
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
cursor.next()
}
println "Client "+getName() + " finished"
```

Do you have any idea what i am missing?

edit:
Damn...I double checked the JProfiler documentation and missed this entry:

**The MongoDB probe works with the official MongoDB driver starting with version 2.11 and higher.**

So I changed the entry inside my pom to version 2.11.3 and now everything works as expected.

Comment: Does JProfiler 8/9 also work with MongoDB 3.0.3 and Morphia 1.9.5? Currently we are not able to get JProfiler to work with the above mentioned :/ Hibernate and JDBC probing are working fine though

Comment: After further testing, it seems that with 3.0.3+ only a tiny sub-group of queries is recognized by JProfiler. The same test-code executed with 2.13.3 reveals a lot more queries (like f.e. the check for master-node every 5 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can profile through integrating JProfiler to the IDE. In below link it shows how to connect it to IntelliJ.

https://medium.com/@ydulanjanii/profiling-mongodb-with-jprofiler-e3aef8860265

Comment: While the link can solve the question it's always better to add some explanation to the answer. If in the future the link will go offline your answer will become completely useless...